# EF Entry doesn't take care about deleted items?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

I'm doing some `CRUD` operations from my model (`ASP.NET MVC`) to my Database, using `Entity Framework`. Here how I Add/Update my entities, within the `Action` of my `Controller`, mapping the `ViewModel` to `Model`:

```
IList<Payments> newPayments = activityViewModel.Payments.Select(p => mapper.Map<PaymentViewModel, Payments>(p)).ToList();

foreach (var payments in newPayments)
{
    ctx.Entry(payments).State = payments.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
}
```

It seems to works nice on new/updated records. But what about the deleted ones? Do I need to subtract the elements in the list and do Delete manually?

Or is there a fancy way in `EF`?

Comment: Because you are getting the collection outside of a DB context  it is not tracking the items so you are responsible for everything. If you had pulled up the collection, removed items and committed the changes inside a DBContext then it would track them for you.

Comment: @PaulSwetz `Because you are getting the collection outside of a DB context` but the `payments` I add also are outside a DB context. Its still able to add/update items.

Comment: You have written logic to set the EntityState for the add/update items.  You must add similar logic for deleted items.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft but its deleted from list, so I can't add any object on "non-exist" elements. Isn't a sort of "compare for missing" items? How would you do it?

Comment: @markzzz yes, that's why you have to continue the pattern you already started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all the entities not in a collection, then you need to find the key values for the rows you want to delete.  Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ef6Test
{
    public class Blog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public BlogDbContext() : base("BlogDbContext") { }
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }


    class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BlogDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BlogDbContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var b = new Blog() { Name = $"Blog {i}" };
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    var p = new Post() { Blog = b, Content = $"Content {i} {j}" };
                    context.Posts.Add(p);
                }
                context.Blogs.Add(b);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
    }
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DbInitializer());

            //get an untracked Blog with its Posts
            Blog blog;
            using (var db = new BlogDbContext())
            {
                blog = db.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).AsNoTracking().First();

            }

            //remmove some posts
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var p in blog.Posts.ToList())
            {
                i++;
                if (i%2 == 0)
                {
                    blog.Posts.Remove(p);
                }
            }


            //delete the posts that have been removed
            using (var db = new BlogDbContext())
            {
                var postIdsToKeep = blog.Posts.Select(p => p.Id);
                var postIdsToDelete = from p in db.Posts.AsNoTracking()
                                    where p.BlogId == blog.Id
                                    where !postIdsToKeep.Contains(p.Id)
                                    select p.Id;

                //construct key-only entities for the Posts to be deleted
                foreach (var pid in postIdsToDelete)
                {
                    var p = new Post() { Id = pid };
                    db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }

                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```